# Need suggestions for calibrating Asus Xtion Pro live sensor

Tags: ros, calibration, asus-xtion-pro-live, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want suggestions from experts here to calibrate the asus xtion pro live sensor. I am running ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04. Also I want to mention I am using openni2 to run the sensor. I read the camera intrinsic and extrinsic calibration tutorial on ros wiki but most of them are written for the kinect sensor. Can anyone here, help me or point me in right direction into how to correctly calibrate the xtion pro live on ROS Hyro? What are the steps I should be careful of? Any blog or video which you can point out giving detailed tutorial and process of calibration.

Thanks

Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207495/need-suggestions-for-calibrating-asus-xtion-pro-live-sensor/) by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 654 on 2015-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-04-21**:
I haven't yet tried it. I just wanted to confirm whether the same set of tutorials will work for the asus xtion pro live on openni2 launch. I hope to do it this week. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I used the intrinsics and extrinsics calibration tools on Asu Xtion pro and it was working nicely.
Have you actually tried thiese tutorials on Asus Xtion ?
 If yes, in what was that unsatisfying ?

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0